# Логи sshd дублируются в двух местах

Tags: linux, ubuntu, ssh, логирование, systemd

Обнаружил, что логи sshd (если конкретнее, сообщения об успешных и неуспешных входах) в моей Ubuntu 18.04 пишутся одновременно в `/var/log/journal` и в `/var/log/auth.log` и тем самым впустую тратят место на диске (а systemd-journald никогда не отличался экономным расходованием места). Где настраиваются оба лога? Можно ли как-то отключить вывод логов sshd в `/var/log/journal` и оставить только `/var/log/auth.log`? (Логи остальных служб мне отключать не нужно.)

Answer (score 3):

1. каталог `/var/log/journal` наполняет *systemd-journald* (один из компонентов (перефразируя бородатую шутку) «неплохой операционной системы *systemd*, которой, жаль, не хватает системы инициализации»).
2. файл `/var/log/auth.log` наполняет *rsyslog* (или *syslog-ng* или т.п.).
3. первичен в наблюдаемых мною системах именно *systemd-journald*: получая новые сообщения, он их заносит в журнал и дублирует в сокет для *rsyslog* (опция `ForwardToSyslog` в `/etc/systemd/journald.conf` по умолчанию равна `yes`). и если отключить *systemd-journald*, то *rsyslog* ничего и не получит.
4. опции «не записывать в журнал то-то и то-то» в программе *systemd-journald*, насколько я вижу, не имеется.
5. отсутствует и возможность убрать при просмотре журала «то-то и то-то» (т.е., из вывода *journalctl*): для этого надо вывод [дополнительно фильтровать](https://superuser.com/q/1198464/454489).

---

итог: разработчиками *systemd* (да продлятся до бесконечности их дни в том месте, куда они попадут после смерти) оставлена всего одна возможность избежать дублирования — на стороне *rsyslog*.

благо это-то вполне возможно. вот такое [правило](http://r3mm3r.net/nastraivaem-rsyslog-na-logirovanie-v-otdelnye-fayly) запретит обработку сообщений от *sshd*:

```
:programname, isequal, "sshd" stop
```

оно должно попасть в конфигурацию раньше описания стандартных лог-файлов. если это описание находится, например, в файле `/etc/rsyslog.d/50-default.conf`, то надо создать файл, имя которого начинается с числа, меньшего пятидесяти. например, `/etc/rsyslog.d/49-sshd.conf`

Answer (score 0):

В архитектурах с systemd делают логер на journal и пересылку в олдскульный лог через rsyslog.

Отключать journal как сервис не очень хорошая идея, потому как может затронуть другие сервисы.

В файле /etc/systemd/journald.conf настроить можно размер под логи или тип хранения логов.

Если конфигурация по умолчанию и есть папка `/var/log/journal/` то journald пишет логи туда. Если этой папки нет - то пишет в tmpfs в папках `/run/log/`.

```
#Storage=auto
```

[Можно задать вручную нужный режим или ограничить используемое место.](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/journald.conf.html#)

Отключить журнал, логи также будут передаваться на сислог и через него в файлы:

```
Storage=none
```

Comment: пс. я обычно отключаю сислог

Comment: Мне нужно убрать только логи sshd, а не все логи вообще

Comment: А то, что написано в ответе, я и так прекрасно знаю (сам же статью в арчевики переводил, хех). Но управлению логами отдельно взятого сервиса это не очень помогает

Comment: ответ оставим, может кому-то ещё пригодится... надо подумать как фильтровать логи

Comment: На просторах гитхаба есть какая-то питоновая утилитка, которая стирает из уже записанных логов логи отдельно взятых служб, но это какой-то дикий костылизм

Comment: https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/513396/43898 вот тут подрезается syslog